# Is there a way to create a new column for values that are in the original column either using Excel or Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have the below Pandas Series with values that look like this:

| Info |
| --- |
| # ID 3.22.33.2 |
| Location: Texas |
| Address: 1321 madeupstreet |
| Name: mike b |
| Address: 6.3.1 |

There are almost 1000 rows with this data so the problem I am having is:

**Question**

Can I run a code in python or Excel to extract the values from these rows in such a way that it would place ID#s on a separate column, Location in a another column ...etc

So it would look something like this:

| IDs | Location | Address | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.22.33.2 | Texas | 1321 Madeupstreet | mike b |

Some items wont have a Name and in that case, could it just leave it blank? or write No name found?

I tried creating separate lists (this data came from a text file) but that method is not working for me, and I do not have any code to share at the moment.so I copy pasted all the values into an excel sheet.

Note (I do not care about the second Address line, so if it is easier to ignore that is fine).

Comment: can you provide a few more rows to see what happens with more ID/location/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the specific series and for the sake of easiness I suggest you can try:

```
df['Index'] = df['Info'].replace("# ","",regex=True).str.split().str[0]
df['Values'] = [' '.join(x) for x in df['Info'].replace("# ","",regex=True).str.split().str[1:]]
output = df.set_index('Index').drop(columns='Info').T
```

Returning:

```
Index          ID Location:           Address:   Name: Address:
Values  3.22.33.2     Texas  1321 madeupstreet  mike b    6.3.1
```

Comment: Happy to know it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `split` the header and values, then `pivot_table`:

```
out = (df['Info']
 .str.split(':|(?<=ID)\s', expand=True)
 .set_axis(['col', 'value'], axis=1)
 .assign(index=lambda d: d['col'].str.endswith('ID').cumsum())
 .pivot_table(index='index', columns='col', values='value', aggfunc='first')
 .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
        # ID             Address Location     Name
1  3.22.33.2   1321 madeupstreet    Texas   mike b
```

Comment: Hi amazing method as well, I tried the first answer and it worked. I appreciate your time and sorry

Comment: This question allowed for plenty of creativity. Brilliant

Comment: @CatDad this one should work if you have more than one ID ;)

Answer (score 0):

It was the row with `ID` entry that caused hastle but here is my solution

I first changed the entry with `ID` to have `:` just like all other rows

```
ID_index = df.Info[0].index('ID')
df.Info[0] =  df.Info[0][:ID_index+2] + ':' + df.Info[0][ID_index+2:]
```

Then split the rows by `:` and transpose the series

```
    new_df = df.Info.str.split(':', expand=True).T
    new_df.columns = new_df.iloc[0].values
    new_df = new_df.iloc[1:]
```

gives

```
        # ID    Location    Address         Name     Address
1   3.22.33.2   Texas   1321 madeupstreet   mike b  6.3.1
```